# jmeter script for JSF with PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jmeter

I want to stress test JSF application (using Primefaces) with Jmeter and I'm facing a strange problem.

Said application saves some textual field and one image field. The workflow of application is that, on image upload control (primefaces) image is stored in session and on save button click application saves textual data as well as image data (from session).

Now the problem is this: I made two post request - one with image data and 2nd with textual data - but the page can't simulate saving.

Is there any way to simulate the process in jmeter?

Answer (score 2):

Given you send the same requests as browser does you should be able to replicate the browser behaviour, just make sure to:

1. Properly build [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler(s)
2. Pay attention to [HTTP Headers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)
3. Correlate dynamic parameters like [JSF ViewState](https://www.lynda.com/Java-EE-tutorials/JSF-ViewState/772341/5025405-4.html)

With regards to point 1 it should be sufficient to just record the requests using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), just make sure to copy the file(s) you're uploading to the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation, this way JMeter will be able to properly capture the requests. See [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more details.

Points 2 and 3 - cross check the requests which are being sent from browser using [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and JMeter's [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener - the requests need to be exactly the same apart from dynamic parameters which need to be [correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)

And don't forget to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan, it should deal with [JSESSIONID](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/08/what-is-jsessionid-in-j2ee-web.html) and other cookies